# Working with NHibernate, ASP.NET MVC and Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, drop-down-menu

We're using ASP.NET MVC together with NHibernate and we'd like to create several Dropdown Lists using Values (custom Class) from the Database. This actually works, but how do I handle the "Empty" value; I mean, the "unselected" DropdownValue? Something like "-- Select --" on the top of the List... Does anyone have experience with this combination NHibernate, ASP.NET MVC and Dropdown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easily handled by using a ViewModel class.   Lets say you have an *OrderView* in your app, which displays an order.  On this view you have a dropdown "Item Type", containing a list of item types.

The model that should be fed to your view should be a class like *OrderViewModel* which contains a list of *ItemType* objects.   When the controller loads the list of ItemType objects from the DB using NHib, it can then insert extra "special" Item Types into the collection, such as one for "--SELECT--".

In other words, don't bind directly to an Nhibernate collection mapping property -- use Nhibernate to load data into a list which you can then manipulate at will.

Comment: hi HokieMike, thanks a lot for your first suggestion! I am using the ViewModel Pattern already. (by the way, it gets trickier if Master/Details Views join the game)
This is how i'm doing it at the moment: On the View I call the Method "AsSelectList" on the custom class property which returns me the SelectList of that dropdown type. Inside this Method, the "--Select--" gets added from database with the IdValue 1. This is working without problems. But if it comes to saving the object, i'd prefer to have "NULL" in the DB if "--Select--" was selected and not the foreign key 1 of "--Select--"...

Answer (score 0):

Best way to have a "--select--" value in Dropdown will be the parameter optionLabel which is available in Html.DropdownList

Then save "null" to your database and you should have a clean way ;)

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("myDropdown",mylist,"--please choose--" %>
```